# How to update whole column in in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-update

Does anyone know how to update whole column in mysql by using java? I need to set online column to 0.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE tablename
SET online = 0;
```

Comment: -4 for not guessing the table name.

Comment: Haha, I'm so stupid. I'm doing this java plugin for like 2 days in a row without sleeping and my brain is empty :D

Answer (score 3):

Don't add the **where** clause in your query.

e.g.

```
update Person set name="XYZ" where id=1;
```

Here you update only a specific resultset.

But the same query without where clause,

```
update Person set name="XYZ".
```

You are updating all of records with name column set to XYZ.

Comment: update whole column in mysql , don't put where clause and you get the whole column to update... e.g. update Person set name="XYZ" where id=1; Here you update only a specific resultset. But the same query without where clause, update Person set name="XYZ". You are updating all of records with name column set to XYZ.

Comment: so put this explanation to your answer , and gave an example to explain your point :)